# How to dismiss share system dialog in Android programatically?

Tags: java, android, mobile, sharing

I have a share bottom sheet and I want to dismiss this bottomsheet manually programatically. How can I do that? It was initially invoked by using Intent.createChooser.

Comment: not sure, can you try `this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh you can't dispatch KeyEvents unless you have root or signature-level access to the system.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent) , maybe, can you provide any link to validate this

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Activity#dispatchKeyEvent() does not call that event. It's only used so the Activity can receive KeyEvents.

Comment: yeah, if somehow we can trigger the back key event then it will work though I know you have a point

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh it's possible through an AcessibilityService, but that's not an ideal method unless you're already using one.

Comment: that might be a solution, sorry can't give you upvote, exhausted daily cap, will do later

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)); does not trigger the event of back press. I already have onBackPressed overridden in my activity. However, I do not want onBackPress to invoke. I just want to trigger the back key as user would normally do when share sheet is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly. When you run the Intent returned by `Intent.createChooser()`, it starts the [ChooserActivity](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ChooserActivity.java).

If you had signature-level system access, you could use `Instrumentation#sendKeySync()`, and if you had root you could use `input keyevent 4`, but neither of these is going to be possible for a general-audience app.

ChooserActivity has an IntentFilter defined in the manifest to listen for `Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER`, but it doesn't listen for anything else, including `Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`, which would normally be the way to do this.

You can use an `AccessibilityService`, and send the `GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK` action from it, but that's probably a little heavy for what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any other workaround that you could think of?

Comment: Another root-only workaround would be to kill the ChooserActivity, but there's nothing for non-root besides an AccessibilityService.